# Maven command "mvn clean jetty:run" and other mvn commands are not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, pom.xml

I am following **Google Cloud documentation** https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-sql for developing an Application. 
As suggested by the documentation, `mvn clean jetty:run` command should be used for testing the application locally. Apart from this, I have tried other commands like `mvn compile` too. Following are the steps which I followed for testing the application locally:-

**Right clicked on my project** -> **Run As** -> **Maven build, then the configuration box launched where I entered the `mvn clean jetty:run` in the Goals text box and clicked Run**

Following is my pom.xml file:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>LiveInBliss</groupId>
  <artifactId>LiveInBliss</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
  <!-- [START resources] -->
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <!-- [END resources] -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.0.M0</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.2.v20170220</version>
</plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
  <version>1.34.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>                        <!-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/ -->
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
<!--
    INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME from Cloud Console > SQL > Instance Details > Properties
    or `gcloud sql instances describe <instance> | grep connectionName`
-->
    <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>live-in-bliss:northamerica-northeast1:liveinbliss-99</INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
    <user>root</user>
    <password>my_password</password>
    <database>liveinbliss</database>
    <sqlURL>jdbc:mysql://google/$liveinbliss?cloudSqlInstance=$live-in-bliss:northamerica-northeast1:liveinbliss-99&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&amp;user=$root&amp;password=$Mohini24&amp;useSSL=false</sqlURL>
  </properties>

</project>
```

and following is my error log:-

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< LiveInBliss:LiveInBliss >-----------------------
[INFO] Building LiveInBliss 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.305 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-08T18:28:24+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Pls do suggest, What changes should I make.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter only **clean jetty:run**, remove mvn.

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting this:- Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.0.M0:run (default-cli) on project LiveInBliss: Failure: Address already in use -> [Help 1]

Comment: This is a different error. You must have specified a port in your jetty configuration which will be used by the embedded jetty server e.g, - <httpConnector><port>8084</port></httpConnector>. Either change this to some other port which is free or stop the application/service which is listening at it.

Comment: Exactly where should I specify this in my pom.xml file? I have not specified any port there as you can see in the pom.xml above. Pls suggest which port and where it should be specified. Thank you

Comment: By default, it runs on port 8080.  
                   https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.1.5.v20140505/jetty-maven-plugin.html           https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-jetty-plugin-examples/

Comment: It's working locally but when I deploy it to the appengine, it simply says No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project and in the plugin groups. But, I have already set it up like this:- <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.66</version>
        </plugin>

Comment: I don't know about com.google.appengine, try checking it's documentation or raise a new question so that someone else can help..